# How to avoid duplicate symbol linker error for constructors when using make in c++

Tags: c++, constructor, makefile

I have a large project with various constructors for custom classes that I have written. For each class exists a header file which contains the class definition and the constructors. In addition, a .cpp file exists for each class that contains the definition of the member functions for that class.

When I invoke make everything compiles fine into .o files. However, the linker complains of duplicate symbols for each of my constructors.

I have tried moving the definitions of the constructors to the .cpp files, but that has not solved my problem.

My makefile is as follows

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
PRJ_SRC_DIR=./source
GENHEADER_DIR=/usr/local/include/genheaders
PRJ_SOURCES= #long list of .cpp files
GENERAL_SOURCES= #long list of .cpp files
SOURCES=$(PRJ_SOURCES:%=$(PRJ_SRC_DIR)/%) $(GENERAL_SOURCES:%=$(GENHEADER_DIR)/%)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=networkMole.out

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE):$(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

All of my constructors are declared within the body of a class and defined at the end of a class.

```
/* class1.hpp */
classOne{ 
    /* Some Code */
    ClassOne();
};
ClassOne::ClassOne(){ /*Code*/}
```

Comment: Can you show an example constructor, along with where it is in the header and cpp file?  When you get the link error, does it say which objects contain the duplicate symbols?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that your makefile does not have dependencies to notice that the headers have changed (and thus the sources should be recompiled before linking) -- meaning your .o's are old. Delete them and rebuild to see if this is the case (and solves your issue).

Comment: @ mah, you are right, my headers are not dependencies of the .o files. Given my makefile and that my sources not only come from different directories but that I have some headers which are without .cpp files and some .cpp files which are without headers, how can I best create such dependencies without being too verbose?